# How does Docker Swarm load balance?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a cluster of 10 Swarm nodes started via `docker swarm join` command

If i want to scale a docker instance to 15 via

```
docker service create --replicas 15
```

how does docker swarm know where to start the container?

is it round-robin or does it take into consideration of compute resource (how much cpu/mem being used)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a service or scale it in the Swarm mode, `scheduler` on `Elected Leader` (one of the managers) will choose a node to run the service on. There are 3 strategies currently available to the leader.

- spread
- binpack
- random

The `spread` and `binpack` strategies compute rank according to a node’s available CPU, its RAM, and the number of containers it has. The `random` strategy uses no computation. It selects a node at random and is primarily intended for debugging.

Under the `spread` strategy, Swarm optimizes for the node with the least number of containers. The `binpack` strategy causes Swarm to optimize for the node which is most packed.

Swarm uses spread by default.
Keep in mind you can `Constraint` Containers on specific nodes too.

**It's not possible to set strategies in docker version 1.12.1 (Latest release to posting date)**

Comment: Where can I find the document in official website?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/swarm/scheduler/strategy.md